# How to setup nginx in front of node in docker for Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I need to setup reverse proxy nginx in front of nodejs app that need to be deployed in google cloud run.

Use Cases
- Need to serve assets gzipped via nginx (I don't want to overhead node for gzip compression)
- To block small DDOS attacks

I didn't find any tutorial to setup nginx and node in cloud run.

Also I need to install PM2 to for node.

How to do this setup in docker? also how can I configure nginx before deploying?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

> I need to setup reverse proxy nginx in front of nodejs app that need
> to be deployed in google cloud run.

Cloud Run already provides a reverse proxy - Cloud Run Proxy. This is the service that load balances, provides custom domains, authentication, etc. for Cloud Run. However, there is nothing in the design of Cloud Run to prevent you from using Nginx as a reverse proxy inside your container. There is nothing in the design of Cloud Run to prevent you from using Nginx as a separate container front-end to another Cloud Run service. Note in the last case you will be paying twice as much as you will need two Cloud Run services, one for the Nginx service URL and another for the node application.

> Use Cases - Need to serve assets gzipped via nginx (I don't want to
> overhead node for gzip compression) - To block small DDOS attacks

You can either perform compression in your node app or in Nginx. The result is the same. The performance impact is the same. Nginx does not provide any overhead savings. Nginx may be more convenient in some cases.

Your comment to block small DDOS attacks. Cloud Run autoscales, which means each Cloud Run instance will have some limited exposure to a DOS. As the DDOS traffic increases, Cloud Run will launch more instances of your container. Without a prior request from you, Cloud Run will stop scaling at 1,000 instances. Nginx will not provide any benefit that I can think of to mitigate a DDOS attack.

> I didn't find any tutorial to setup nginx and node in cloud run.

I am not aware of a specific document covering Nginx and Cloud Run. However, you do not need one. Any document covering Nginx and Docker will be fine. If you want to run Nginx in the same container as your node application you will need to write a custom script to launch both Nginx and Node.

> Also I need to install PM2 to for node.

Not possible. PM2 has a user interface and GUI. Cloud Run only exposes $PORT over HTTP from a Cloud Run instance.

> How to do this setup in docker? also how can I configure nginx before
> deploying?

There are numerous tutorials on the Internet for setting up Nginx and Docker.

Two examples below. There are hundreds of examples on the Internet.

- [How to run NGINX as a Docker container](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-run-nginx-as-a-docker-container/)
- [Deploying NGINX and NGINX Plus on Docker](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/)

I have answered each of your questions. Now some advice:

1. Using Nginx with Cloud Run does not make any sense with a Node.js application. Just run your node application and let Cloud Run Proxy do its job.
2. Compression is CPU intensive. Cloud Run is designed for HTTP style microservices that are small, fast, and compact. You will pay for increased CPU time. If you have content that needs to be compressed, compress it first and serve the content compressed. There are cases where compression in Cloud Run is useful and/or correct, but look at your design and optimize where possible. Static content should be served by Cloud Storage, for example.

Cloud Run can handle a Node.js application easily with excellent performance and scalability provided that you follow its design criteria and purpose.

Key factors to keep in mind:

- Low cost, you only pay for requests. Overlapping requests have the same cost as one request.
- Stateless. Containers are shut down when not needed which means you must design for restarts. Store state elsewhere such as a database.
- Only serves traffic on port $PORT, which today is 8080.
- Public traffic can be either HTTP or HTTPS. Traffic from the Cloud Run Proxy to the container is HTTP.
- Custom domain names. Cloud Run makes HTTPS for URLs very easy.

  UPDATE: Only HTTPS is now supported for the public endpoint (Public Traffic).

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer and for the effort you have put on it.

I have read that NodeJs is not good for gzipping, even though compression is bit cpu intensive task, right? that's why I need nginx in front.

But can't PM2 run on cloud run? so how can I restart node when node crashes with unhandled exception or something similar?

Thanks again

Comment: If your container crashed, Cloud Run will terminate it and launch a new container. I think you are confusing what service Cloud Run provides. It starts a container when an HTTP request is received and is shutdown when there are no more requests to process after an idle period. Cloud Run is not an "always running" service unless there is HTTP traffic to keep the container busy. Regarding compression, where have you read that node.js cannot compress data efficiently? Wrong assumption. The benefits received by Nginx will not offset the complexity of having two containers, one for compression.

Comment: I can't find any document about "Cloud Run Proxy". Do you mean "Endpoints for Cloud Run" ?

Comment: @DaNeSh - No, I do not mean `Endpoints`. The Cloud Run Poxy is built into the Cloud Run (Managed) service. I described its features in my answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley Can you please give more details on the DDoS attacks part. There is no way NGINX can be helpful in this aspect to block minor DoS attacks? I'm assuming at-least we can rate limit at NGINX level for lesser cost. Isn't it?

Comment: @Ayyappa - I did not say Nginx would help with a DDoS. I suggest creating a new question.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should consider using a different approach.

Running multiple processes in a single container is not a best practice. The more common implementation of a proxy as you describe is to use 2 containers (the proxy is often called the sidecar) but this is not possible with Cloud Run.

Google App Engine may be more suitable.

App Engine Flexible permits deployments of containers that are proxied (behind the scenes) by Nginx. You may use static content with Flexible and can incorporate a CDN. App Engine Standard addresses your needs too.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/serving-static-files
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime

Like Cloud Run, App Engine is serverless but provides more flexibility and is a more established service. App Engine integrates with more (all?) GCP services too whereas Cloud Run is limited to a subset.

Alternatively, you may consider Kubernetes (Engine). This provides almost limitless flexibility but requires more ops. As you're likely aware, there's a Cloud Run implementation that runs atop Kubernetes, Istio and Knative.

Cloud Run is a compelling service but it is only appropriate if you can meet its (currently) contrained requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort put on writing this.

I've tried app engine and cloud run at the same time and what I noticed are 1. App engine deployment is slower 2. Time for serving a request is higher than cloud run (app engine takes ~700ms for a request and cloud run serves the same request in 300-400ms). That's drive me to move with cloud run.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, Cloud Run deployments are very fast. Beside being annoying this should mostly affects you not your customers. Time to first response is disappointing. Given that you can't elegantly solve the sidecar problem with Cloud Run, you may have no alternative but to file FRs against Google

Answer (score 2):

I have good news for you. I have written a blog post about exactly what you needed with sample code.

This example puts NGINX in the front (port 8080 on Cloud Run) while proxying the traffic selectively to another service running in the same container (on port 8081).

- Read the blog post: https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-multiple-processes-easy-way/
- Source code: https://github.com/ahmetb/multi-process-container-lazy-solution

Comment: awesome example, thanks for going through the proper/different init processes. You say it's "not super production-ready." What are some tips, directions, things to look at to make it more production ready?

Comment: Also just tried the solution. Works locally, but not in Cloud Run. Any insight into why? I get 502 Bad Gateway. Seems like the web app has a hard time starting up (node.js in my case). I see it attempting to start the server, but no regular or error logs after that.

Comment: thanks for publishing the solution.  it makes sense.  i guess the issue is cold starts?  i'm currently using the GCE load balancer with forwarding rules.  It seems the pricing is more complex than AWSes' ALB, which has a fixed cost.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Cloud Compute Systems**

To understand GCP Computing, please see the below picture first:

[image]

For your case, I totally recommend you to use App Engine Flex to deploy your application. It supports docker container, nodejs,... To understand HOW TO DEPLOY nodejs to GAE Flex, please visit this page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart

You can install some third party libraries if you want. Moreover, GCP supports the global/internal load balancer, you can apply it into your GAE services.

Comment: Do they have any documents? Can you put them here?