# Cloud Run needs NGINX or not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am using cloud run for my blog and a work site and I really love it.
I have deployed python APIs and Vue/Nuxt Apps by containerising it according to the google tutorials.
One thing I don't understand is why there is no need to have NGINX on the front.

```
# Use the official lightweight Node.js 12 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:12-slim

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install --only=production

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Run the web service on container startup.
RUN npm run build
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libpq-dev \
gcc
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn -b :$PORT --workers=4 main:server
```

All this works without me calling Nginx ever.
But I read alot of articles whereby people bundle NGINX in their container. So I would like some clarity. Are there any downsides to what I am doing?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890126/how-to-setup-nginx-in-front-of-node-in-docker-for-cloud-run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One considerable advantage of using NGINX or a static file server is the **size of the container image**. When serving SPAs (without SSR), all you need is to get the bundled files to the client. There's no need to bundle build dependencies or runtime that's needed to compile the application.

Your first image is copying whole source code with dependencies into the image, while all you need (if not running SSR) are the compiled files. NGINX can give you the "static site server" that will only serve your build and is a lightweight solution.

Regarding python, unless you can bundle it somehow, it looks ok to use without the NGINX.

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! I was struggling to find a good answer.
So essentially for the nodejs case, if it was an SPA I could just include nginx to serve the static files.
But, if it was an SSR, i wouldnt need it?

Also, firebase hosting has advantages over NGINX Container for SPA apps right?

Comment: Regarding Firebase, I suggest you use that, it's far simpler for SPAs than running it on Cloud Run. Now SSR, you may need the runtime with the compiled bundle, but this is framework-specific. Look into the Vue docs on how to serve minimal bundles for the SSRs :)

Comment: In a nutshell, Cloud Run needs container images that run a web server. You can write your own server (in Go, Java, Python, Node.js ...) to serve your blog, or run nginx, Apache, HAProxy, Envoy or whatever in front of your application –that part is up to you. That said not all languages provide an HTTP server out of the box (e.g. PHP).

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I understand that, but I am curious, does Cloud Run have a proxy on the front and thats why if I just run gunicorn it is sufficient because cloud run has something like Nginx on the front?

Comment: I am not sure why you want to know the answer to that question. Gunicorn is “the” production ready proxy for your Python app. The answer to your question actually won’t help you. But yes Cloud Run has a proxy in front of your apps to load balance between containers and perform authentication etc.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google - ahhhh the reason why I am asking is because if I were to spin up a compute instance, I would need to configure NGINX to receive HTTP requests that are routed to GUnicorn. So I am trying to understand the cloud run perspective to this and why I only need Gunicorn and not NGINX. So sorry I'm still learning all this

Comment: No worries. Even in a GCE VM, `gunicorn` can directly serve as a HTTP server as long as you bind it to port 80, you do not need nginx for that.

Comment: Do you serve JSON files like "Apple app site association" and "assetlinks.json" using Gunicorn as well? (I am using nginx currently and thinking of removing it, learning to abide by the prinicpal of 1 container 1 service.