# How to set in a Dockerfile an nginx in front of the same container (google cloud run)? I tried making a python server (odoo) handle http/2

Tags: nginx, odoo, http2, google-cloud-run

Thanks in advance. My question is, how to set in a Dockerfile an nginx in front of a container? I saw other questions [5], and it seems that the only way to allow http/2 on odoo in cloud run is to create an nginx container, as sidecars are not allowed in gcrun. But I also read that with supervisord it can be done. Has anyone been able do that so to handle http/2 and so to increase the cloud run max request quota?

I wanted to to try this: in the entrpoint.sh, write a command to install nginx, and then set its configuration to be used as a proxy to allow http2. But, I ask you here as I'm not sure if it'll work, as I read in [2] that nginx won't work with a python server.

The whole story: I'm deploying an odoo ce on google cloud run + cloud sql. I configured one odoo as a demo with 5 blogposts and when I tried to download it, it says that the request was too large. Then, I imagined this was because of the 32MB of cloud run request quota [1], as the backup size was 52 MB. Then, I saw that the quota for http/2 connections was unlimited, so I activated http/2 button in cloud run. Next, when I accessed the service an error relating "connection failure appeared".

To do so I thought of two ways: one, was upgrading the odoo http server to one that can handle http/2 like Quark. This first way seems impossible to me, because it would force me to rewrite many pieces of odoo, maybe. Then, the second option that I thought of was running in front of the odoo container (that runs a python web server on a Werkzeug), an nginx. I read in the web that nginx could upgrade connections to http/2. But, I also read that cloud run was running its internal load balancer [2]. So, then my question: would it be possible to run in the same odoo container an nginx that exposes this service on cloud run?

---

References:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas 
[2] [Cloud Run needs NGINX or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794069/cloud-run-needs-nginx-or-not) 
[3] https://linuxize.com/post/configure-odoo-with-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy/ 
[4] https://github.com/odoo/docker/tree/master/14.0 
[5] [How to setup nginx in front of node in docker for Cloud Run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890126/how-to-setup-nginx-in-front-of-node-in-docker-for-cloud-run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has anyone been able do that so to handle http/2 and so to increase the cloud run max request quota?

Handling HTTP/2 does not help you increase your maximum requests per container limit on Cloud Run.

HTTP/2 only helps you reuse TCP connections to send concurrent requests over a single connection, but Cloud Run does not really count connections so you are not on the right track here. HTTP/2 won't help you.

Cloud Run today already supports 1000 container instances (with 250 concurrent requests in preview) so that's 250,000 simultaneous requests for your service. If you need more, contact support.

> But, I ask you here as I'm not sure if it'll work, as I read in [2] that nginx won't work with a python server.

Sounds incorrect.

If you configure a multi-process container you can run Python behind nginx on Cloud Run. But as you said, Cloud Run does not need nginx.

Overall you don't need HTTP/2 in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks you so much @AhmetB - Google :) But I have one doubt: ok, "I agree Handling HTTP/2 does not help you increase your maximum requests per container limit on Cloud Run", but is it going to increase the "maximum request size"? I forgot to write this keyword :(. Because my problem with downloading the backup is the **max request size**; in the cloud run web it says it can be increase by handling http/2 connections.